# Javascript turn <c:out value into date

Tags: javascript, date, jsp

I am trying to turn my <c: out value into a Javascript date but when I try it I am constantly getting invalid date. This the string that I am trying to turn into a Javascript dateTime.

> 24-02-2021 17:34:27

I am getting this value by doing the following:

```
var d = ('<c:out value="${post.end}"/>');
```

And then I try changing it into a date by the following code:

```
var date1 = new Date(d);
console.log(date1);
```

And this is where I am getting the invalid date

> Invalid Date

Now I'm not sure if this was because I have time at the end of the string, so I've also tried removing the time at the end by using substring to have the date string as:

> 24-02-2021

But yet this still has the same error. I have also replaced all the - with / so the date appears like this:

> 24/02/2021

What can I do to make sure that this date is a 'valid' date so I can use it within my code.

Comment: What is the ouput of `console.log(d)` and `console.log(typeof d)`?

Comment: the output of `console.log(d) = 24-02-2021 17:34:27 ` and the output of `console.log(typeof d) = string ` and when I turn it into a date - well try to. The output of `console.log(typeof date1) = object `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date string format is wrong.  Please see the [MDN reference for the Date built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object).

You could do something like this:

```js
d = d.split(' ')[0] // '24-02-2021'
const [day, month, year] = d.split('-')
const date1 = new Date(year, month, day)
```